# How to remove a specific character (",") in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort, removing-whitespace

I basically want to remove the last comma "," from my array of 12 integers. My output goes like `{23, 45, 54, 56, 67, 87, 89, 90, 76, 89, 87, 23, }`  whereas I want to remove the last comma and space it creates after the comma.

Sample output:

```
{23, 45, 54, 56, 67, 87, 89, 90, 76, 89, 87, 23}
```

My task is to basically sort the integers using bubble sorting method in ascending order. And my output basically shows the sorting at each stage and a final sorted array. I want to remove the last comma and the space it creates from the sorting at each stage, final sorted array, and random generated array. I basically provided comments in my code which will help you find each thing.

Please do not make this overly complicated

Code:

```
// Create a class and method
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

// Clear screen
System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
System.out.flush();

// Initialize a int array with the limit of 12
int[] numbers = new int[12];

// Create a statement 
System.out.println("Random Generated Array:");

System.out.print("{");

// Start a for loop to print random numbers
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
  numbers[x] = (int) (Math.random() * 101); // So that it prints random numbers from 0 to 100 (inclusive)

  // Print out the 12 random numbers
  System.out.print(numbers[x] + ", ");
}
System.out.print("}");

// Create space
System.out.println();
System.out.println();

// Create a statement 
System.out.println("Sorting At Each Stage:");

// Start looping numbers until 12
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

  // Start looping numbers and comparing it to the "i" values
  for (int j = i; j < numbers.length; j++) {
    if (numbers[j] < numbers[i]) {

      // Swap the positions of the numbers with the variable "temp"
      int temp = numbers[j];
      numbers[j] = numbers[i];
      numbers[i] = temp;
    }

    // Create space
    System.out.println();
    
    // Use a for loop to print numbers at each stage of sorting
    System.out.print("{");
    for (int k = 0; k < numbers.length; k++) {
      System.out.print(numbers[k] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.print("}");
    System.out.println();
  }
}

// Create space
System.out.println();
System.out.println("\nBubble Sorted Array:");
System.out.print("{");

// Use a for loop to print the final sorted numbers in ascending order
for (int a = 0; a < numbers.length; a++) {
  System.out.print(numbers[a] + ", ");
}

System.out.print("}");

// Create space
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement to see if the index is `== numbers.length - 1`. If so, don't print the comma because this is the last element in the array.

Comment: @ggorlen - What if there is only one element? It will still be printed as `{<<num>>, }`. There is a bit more to consider .

Comment: No, that's not the case. If there's only one element, then `i == numbers.length - 1` will be true and the comma won't print.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use an `if` condition in your `for` loop to not place a comma on the last number:

```
// Start a for loop to print random numbers
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
  numbers[x] = (int) (Math.random() * 101); // So that it prints random numbers from 0 to 100 (inclusive)
  if(x + 1 == numbers.length)
      //Print out random number with no comma as it's the last
      System.out.print(numbers[x]);
  else
      // Print out the 12 random numbers
      System.out.print(numbers[x] + ", ");
}
```

Comment: why did u do x + 1?

Comment: @User234 It's a way to check if you are on the last iteration. The loop will break when `x == numbers.length`.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to see an alternate way to join an array into a string you could consider the functionality that came with Java 8 streams.

This streams the array, mapping each element to a string using String::valueOf and then collecting them together with a delimiter of ", ".  I simply add a brace to either end to make it match what you were doing.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class so64395137 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = { 23, 45, 54, 56, 67, 87, 89, 90, 76, 89, 87, 23 };
        String strNumbers = "{" + Arrays.stream(numbers)
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
                + "}";
        System.out.println(strNumbers);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
{23, 45, 54, 56, 67, 87, 89, 90, 76, 89, 87, 23}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added an `if` in your loop whereby if it is the last iteration, don't add the extra bits.

```
    // Create a class and method
    class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Clear screen
        System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
        System.out.flush();

        // Initialize a int array with the limit of 12
        int[] numbers = new int[12];

        // Create a statement 
        System.out.println("Random Generated Array:");

        System.out.print("{");

        // Start a for loop to print random numbers
        for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
          numbers[x] = (int)(Math.random() * 101); // So that it prints random numbers from 0 to 100 (inclusive)
          if (x == numbers.length) {
            // Print out the 12 random numbers
            System.out.print(numbers[x]);
          } else {
            System.out.print(numbers[x] + ", ")
          }
          System.out.print("}");

          // Create space
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();

          // Create a statement 
          System.out.println("Sorting At Each Stage:");

          // Start looping numbers until 12
          for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

            // Start looping numbers and comparing it to the "i" values
            for (int j = i; j < numbers.length; j++) {
              if (numbers[j] < numbers[i]) {

                // Swap the positions of the numbers with the variable "temp"
                int temp = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = temp;
              }

              // Create space
              System.out.println();

              // Use a for loop to print numbers at each stage of sorting
              System.out.print("{");
              for (int k = 0; k < numbers.length; k++) {
                System.out.print(numbers[k] + ", ");
              }
              System.out.print("}");
              System.out.println();
            }
          }

          // Create space
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("\nBubble Sorted Array:");
          System.out.print("{");

          // Use a for loop to print the final sorted numbers in ascending order
          for (int a = 0; a < numbers.length; a++) {
            System.out.print(numbers[a] + ", ");
          }

          System.out.print("}");

          // Create space
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();
        }
      }


System.out.println();
System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy way to do it, just create an array to hold a String value of the number.  Then use the `String.join()` method to do the work for you.

```
int[] numbers = new int[12];
String[] strings = new String[numbers.length];
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
    numbers[x] = (int) (Math.random() * 101); // So that it prints random numbers from 0 to 100 (inclusive)
    strings[x] = Integer.toString(numbers[x]);
}
System.out.printf("{%s}%n",
        String.join(", ", strings));
```

Prints something like

```
{3, 11, 24, 83, 36, 58, 22, 27, 43, 12, 30, 79}
```